# How to log data only when a ksh script has been executed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, ksh

I'm trying to log the elapsed time (time it took to execute) a specific line of command in a ksh script.

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/ksh -p
now=$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M")
start_time=$SECONDS
*command*
end_time=$SECONDS
elapsed_time=$((end_time-start_time))
echo $elapsed_time > /path_to_log_file/$now.log
```

I want to log the elapsed time ONLY when the script/command is executed.

Currently, this code is generating a log file every minute, even when the script hasn't been executed yet.
And it's not logging the correct elapsed time for some reason, it keeps changing numbers every couple of seconds, preventing the actual elapsed time from being recorded because it keeps overwriting it.

What am I missing here?

How can I create the log file and record the elapsed time to it only when the script is executed, and not every minute?

Comment: `ksh` does not have $SECONDS, that is bash afaik. Also you need to echo `$elapsed_time` and not run it directly.

Comment: @jetchisel what can I use instead of $SECONDS in ksh?

Comment: re: replacing `$SECONDS` ... if all you want is the difference in seconds, consider making 2x `date` calls and formatting the output as 'number of seconds since epoch (1Jan1970)'; then perform the subtraction on this pair of seconds (since epoch); `start_time=$(date '+%s') ... end_time=$(date '+%s') ... elapsed_time=$((end_time - start_time))`

Comment: `$SECONDS` should work. Can you explain why the script is called more than once? Something in `crontab`? Can you test after replacing `*command*`  with `sleep 5` ?